# Measuring time parallely to looped sigwait in C

Tags: c, time, parallel-processing, signals, posix

I have a main proccess which sends signal to the children, like this:

```
void handleInputs(query_data *q_data)
{
    char input[DEFAULT_INPUT_SIZE];
    while(1)
    {

        if(fgets(input,DEFAULT_INPUT_SIZE,stdin)==NULL) ERR("FGETS");
        input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';
        if(!strcmp(input,"exit"))
        {
            kill(0,SIGTERM);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        else if(!strcmp(input,"index"))
            kill(0,SIGUSR2);

        else if(!strcmp(input,"status"))
            kill(0,SIGUSR1);    
        else
        {
            char* token = strtok(input, " ");
            if(!token) printf("Wrong input\n");
            else
            {
                if(!strcmp(token,"query"))
                {
                    initializeQueryNumbers(q_data,token);
                    createQueryThread(q_data);
                }
                else printf("Wrong input\n");
            }
            
        }   
    }
}
```

Then I have a child processes which wait for signals using sigwait in a loop like this:

```
void waitForSignals(data* ch_data)
{
   
    char* pid_directory = strConcat(ch_data->dir, "/.numf_pid");
    int signo;
    for(;;)
    {
        //how to make this block independent to the sigwait
        printf("time elapse: %ld  interval: %d\n",time(NULL)-ch_data->end, ch_data->i);
        if((time(NULL)- ch_data->end)>ch_data->i && ch_data->status ==0)
        {
            printf("Time elapsed from the last indexing > %d\n",ch_data->i);
            createIndexingThread(ch_data);
        }
       //end here

        if(sigwait(&(ch_data->mask), &signo)) ERR("SIGWAIT");
        switch(signo)
        {
            case SIGUSR1:
                if(ch_data->status == 1)
                {
                    printf("Indexing in progress for directory: %s\n",ch_data->dir);
                    printf("Time elapsed: %ld\n", time(NULL)- ch_data->start);
                }
                else printf("No indexing in progress for directory: %s\n",ch_data->dir);
                break;
            case SIGUSR2:
                if(ch_data->status ==0) 
                    createIndexingThread(ch_data);
                else printf("Indexing already in progess for directory: %s\n",ch_data->dir);
                break;
            case SIGTERM:
                if(remove(pid_directory)<0) ERR("REMOVE");
                free(pid_directory);
                if(pthread_cancel(ch_data->tid)==0)
                    printf("Stopped the indexing of directory %s\n",ch_data->dir);
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }

        
    }
    if(pthread_join(ch_data->tid,NULL)) ERR("PTHREAD_JOIN");
}
```

My child proccess creates thread which does some indexing. I want to create such thread when signaled SIGUSR2 from main proccess (which is working fine) or when time elapsed from last indexing is bigger than some user-given time (stored in ch_data->i). However right now the block between the comments only comes alive after I send some signal from the main proccess. What is the best way to make it work in parallel?

Comment: `input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';` fails if `strlen()` is zero or the string doesn't end with a newline.

Comment: Doesn't fgets always add '\n' at the end? I tried empty inputs and '0' and it works just fine.

Comment: Regarding input and `fgets`, try inputting something equal to or larger than `DEFAULT_INPUT_SIZE` in length.

Comment: It works fine with big inputs as well. This isn't the issue I'm having.

Comment: We know it's not *the* problem, but it is *a* problem. And the less unrelated problems your [mcve] have the simpler it will be for us to help you. As for the `fgets` problem lets say that `DEFAULT_INPUT_SIZE ` is `2`. You give `ab\n` as input. `fgets` will only read the `a` and the contents of `input` will be `a\0`. Using `strlen(input) - 1` will overwrite the `a` making the string `\0\0`. Use [`strcspn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcspn) instead, as in `input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = '\0'`, it will do the right thing no matter if there's a newline in the string or not.

Comment: *Doesn't fgets always add '\n' at the end?*  No, [`fgets()` doesn't *add* anything](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.2):  "The fgets function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by n from the stream pointed to by stream into the array pointed to by s. No additional characters are read after a new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-file. A null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array." Read that *carefully* to understand exactly what `fgets()` does and doesn't do - too-long lines won't end with `\n`

Comment: The `ch_data` access strikes me as unsafe.  If I understand correctly that that structure is updated by another thread, you need memory barrier protections (a mutex) to ensure correct behavior.

Comment: As a small point, that loop would be easier to read if the indexer were invoked only once:  `if (got_usr2 || time_elapsed) createIndexingThread(...)`.  The `pthread_join` might be misguided, as I think you'll ignore TERMs and USR1s during indexer execution.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are asking how to schedule a threaded operation performed either *upon a signal* or *upon time elapsed* since the most recent operation, whichever comes first.

You might use [`sigtimedwait(interesting_sigs, NULL, timeout)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigtimedwait.html) instead of `sigwait`, recomputing your *timeout* as needed.

You might [arm a POSIX *timer*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/timer_create.html) to launch the operation (or, perhaps, to signal yourself).  You'll need to check that the operation hasn't been performed too recently, and you'll need to re-arm (reschedule) the next timer appropriately, perhaps at the end of every operation.

You might simply have *an idle-looping background thread* that does what a timer would do.  Sometimes these are easier to reason about than `sigevent` timers.

You might incorporate an event-driven framework like [*libevent*](http://libevent.org) that knows how to handle timeouts and signals and not worry about the implementation.  You'll likely still need to recompute the expiry, however.

Comment: I managed to do this with combination of sigpending and sigwait. Thanks anyway

Comment: @MichałFilipiak, how?  Neither of those functions introduces a timing mechanic.  Do you want to post an answer to your own question?